# How to call tanstack's vue-query get request inside a method?

Tags: rest, vuejs3, tanstackreact-query, tanstack

I need to query an API as a side-effect of an action and I am trying to use @tanstack/vue-query. Whenever I try to call useQuery inside a function, it throws an error, `vue-query hooks can only be used inside setup() function or functions that support injection context.`

For example:

api.js

```
export const getAPIRequest = (url, params={}) => useQuery({
    queryKey: [url, params],
    queryFn: fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    })
})
```

component.vue

```
<script setup>
const getDetails = () => {
    const { data: data } = getAPIRequest('/some-url')
    return data
}
</script>

<template>
    <button @click="getDetails">Click Here</button>
</template>
```

I tried to find a better way to query API from inside a function but I concluded that vue-query can only be called from setup function only. One hack that I came across was answered in this github discussion [thread](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/5178).

Is it true that we can use vue-query only inside setup function? If true, I am not sure how should I structure my project. I have to design side effects that come from button click or typing. Should I move those side effects to POST requests to avoid this situation or is there a better way?

I want to continue using @tanstack/vue-query as it has caching, updating data in background, reactive responses and many more. Is there a better option?

Comment: It looks to me like you ***are*** using `useQuery` inside a `setup` function (`<script setup>` contents are, technically, the contents of that component's `setup` function). There's a good chance renaming `getAPIRequest` to `useApiRequest` will fix the issue. The linting rule checks the name patterns up the callstack chain, making sure the `use*` naming pattern of composables is kept (and you're breaking that pattern with `getAPIRequest`)

Comment: The logic behind the linting rule: check if any `use*` functions are called anywhere outside of `setup` functions (which includes `<script setup>` contents) or outside of functions also named `use*`, which, in turn, share the same usage limitation. In other words, you can call a composable inside another composable (nest composables, any number of levels deep), because ultimately the parent composable can only be used inside `setup`.

Comment: After further clarification from comments by @tao it seems that tanstack's vue-query is designed for efficiently fetching and managing data to be used or displayed within a Vue.js component. The key idea is to query the data directly on the component level, without the need to wrap it in a function to be called later.

Comment: For scenarios like mine, where queries are required as side effects of an action and don't necessarily need to be cached or persist for later use, a simple fetch API can be a suitable alternative. In such cases, there might not be a need for the additional features and caching mechanisms provided by vue-query.